# Does this asymptotic density property has an established name?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, terminology

Let $A_n \subset X$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) be a sequence of subsets of a topological space $X$. Consider the following property:

(1) *For any infinite set $I \subset \mathbb{N}$ the union $\bigcup_{n \in I} A_n$ is dense in $X$.*

This can be equivalently rephrased as

(1') *For any open set $U \subset X$ the set $\{ n \in \mathbb{N} \ : \ A_n \cap X = \emptyset \}$ is finite.*

If $X$ is compact and metrizable and $d$ is a metric on $X$ then (1) is equivalent to

(2) *For any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $n_0$ such that $A_n$ is $\varepsilon$-dense in $X$ for each $n \geq n_0$.*

(Here, a set $A \subset X$ is $\varepsilon$-dense if for any $x \in X$ there exists $y \in A$ with $d(x,y) < \varepsilon$.)

This seems like a rather basic property so I would suppose it has an established name, but I can't seem to find one in the literature. Is there one?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure that I see why this is a "basic property".  What results follow from this property?  Where does it come up?  Why is it an interesting property?

Comment: this definition resembles to me some selection principles (a lot of work done by Marion Scheepes, Boaz Tsaban, others) so I googled "topology selectively dense" but didn't find exactly the same definition. At any rate, you might be interested in some papers that might perhaps be related: http://www.topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v32/tp32002.pdf and http://www.topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v37/tp37012.pdf You might browse the literature about "selection principles in mathematics" to see if you find the property that you define. There is a paper:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0312182.pdf